# How does the compiler detect the String is a Regular Expression?

Tags: java, regex

I am still a beginner in Java but as far as I know, in order to use regular expressions I have to write it in `[ ]` so why this works and how the JVM knows it is regular expressions and not just some string?

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+$" , "");
```

Comment: It has no idea it's a regular expression. It's just a string.

Comment: See [*`replaceAll()`*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) help: *Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement*. It is the method first argument that is parsed as a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the JVM has been given instructions to parse the first argument of `replaceAll()` method as a regex pattern.

Comment: so the [ ] are not necessary just in this method ?

Comment: They are if you want to use them as a **part** of the regex formula.

Comment: From the terminology point of view, it is more appropriate to use a regex *pattern*, not regex *formula*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew indeed.